# How to make <a> tag take 100% height of <li> element

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to make my `<a>` take 100% height of `<li>` element and i want to do this because when i hover over `<a>` i want it to get background color and to change its `color` to white.

this is how it should look like
[image]

I have tried giving my `<a>` `height:100%`

but this is my result
[image]

*on second picture i cut out the piece and zoomed it in so you guys can see better*

i found one answer on other stack overflow thread where you would give `<ul>` `display:table` and give `height:0` and then give `<li>` `height:100%` but it doesnt work for me.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT IM USING BOOTSTRAP 4.0.0alpha and SASS(SCSS)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="topContact hidden-md-down">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="contactInfo">
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><a href=""><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>info@reen.com</a></li>
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>+00 (123) 456 78 90</li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="socialIcons ml-auto">
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-behance"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="d-inline-block"><a href=""><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.topContact{
background-color: #f5f7fa;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e9ed;
ul{
    padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
    margin:0;
}
a:hover{
    background: indigo;
}
a{
    height: 100%;
}
.contactInfo li,
.contactInfo a,
.socialIcons a{
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #506a85;

}
.contactInfo a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00bc9c;

}
.contactInfo svg,{
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.contactInfo li{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

}

Comment: `a {display:block` or `inline-block`; `min-height:100%` }

Comment: apply style `a { display: block; }` and check

Comment: i have tried giving `<a>` display block but it does not work

Comment: `li{padding:0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a child element to assume 100% height of the parent element, the parent element must have its size set. Its not enough to give your `<li>` element a font size for its `<a>` child to extend its height to cover it. The `<li>` must inherit the height from its parent or have it defined. Also, your `<a>` element must be a `block` or `inline-block` element to accept height.

Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul#socialIcons, ul#socialIcons>li { margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; }
    ul#socialIcons>li>a { display:block; font-size:1em; margin:0px; padding:0.5em; }
</style>
```

Also I recommend that you take a look at the concept of HTML box model: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Thanks this works i gave my `<a>` `display:block` and `padding:10px 5px`.

Comment: Glad it helped! I noticed you are using the units of pixels. This will not scale well for different screens. I recommend that you use `em` units, although this will probably require you to change the entirety of your design at this point.

Comment: Just want to add that it's best to instead make <a> element a block, and let it stretch the <li> element with no height defined for <li> element instead.